# Marketing Cloud integration with Veeva CRM

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, veeva

As I am new for the integration part so my query may very basic. We want to integrate the Marketing cloud and Veeva CRM so Marketing Cloud Connect will work as same like Salesforce or any other connector need to install to integrate these two environment. Please also let me know if any limitations after integration between SFMC and Veeva.

Thanks in advance for you understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer their documentation [Veeva Marketing Cloud](https://crmhelp.veeva.com/doc/Content/CRM_topics/Integration/Marketing_Cloud_Integration/MarketingCloudOverview.htm)

In terms of capabilities, it is very very limited. You can only push from a Data Extension to MultiChannelActivity object in Veeva CRM. That's all

For any other data flow, you'll have to leverage the standard Marketing Cloud connect

Comment: Thanks @Maneesh. Could you please also confirm if we can read the data from Veeva CRM object to marketing cloud and  as you suggested to leverage the MC connect, Is this possible to use the Marketing cloud connect to integrate the data between MC and Veeva?

Comment: You have to tell me exactly what you want to integrate between Veeva and SFMC

Comment: We want to transmit the suggestions from SFMC to Veeva CRM. Is this feasible to upload the suggestion directly into suggestion object after integration? Please suggest

Comment: Veeva Connector won't help you for transmitting Suggestions. You can use some middleware like Informatica. Or you can write Apex jobs in CRM to pull from SFMC

Comment: @Maneesh you are saying "For any other data flow, you'll have to leverage the standard Marketing Cloud connect" do you know anything where I could find detailled information on that?

Comment: @GretaSchellpeper check this - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_marketing_cloud_connect.htm&type=5

Comment: @Maneesh thanks! I am aware of this link and MC connect in general, but I just wonder how it will work with veeva as it says that it is quite limited in comparison to the connection to a core product of Salesforce. Do you know where there is any information to find about data flow possibilities between veeva and SFMC? I need to estimate how complex integration will be.

Comment: Can you connect with me on LinkedIn and we can chat about it ? we can have a quick call if you like @GretaSchellpeper

Comment: @Maneesh sure! Under which name can I find you in linkedin`?

Comment: Maneesh Gupta - CRM & digital marketing automation

Answer (score 0):

Maneesh is right about the Veeva Connector, which has limited data exchange. However, SFMC does have their own connectors, that can facilitate easily a bi-directional data integrations, supporting all Veeva CRM objects including the Suggestions. Please see this article about this integration: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_marketing_cloud_connect.htm&type=5